# Break apart timespan/duration group by hour segments

Tags: vb.net

I have an excel sheet that has 3 columns

```
User  order    time

AAA   20      8:00:02

AAA   30      9:00:10

AAA    12     11:20:00

BBB   10      9:30:30

BBB    5        12:30:00

BBB    8        17:00:00
```

Any idea on how to sum up the orders by hours, ex: from 8 to 10h how many order been processed by a user AAA.

Here is part of my code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim timepick As System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    TextBox1.Text = DateTimePicker1.Text
    TextBox2.Text = timepick.ToShortDateString.ToString()

    Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = String.Format(ConnectionNoHeader, FileName)}
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(
            <Text>
                SELECT 
                 order
                     time,
                          user, 
                                date
                    FROM [<%= SheetName %>$] 
        WHERE date =#<%= TextBox2.Text %>#
            </Text>.Value,
        cn)

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        dt.AcceptChanges()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of DataRow)) = dt.AsEnumerable() _
        .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("USER"), Function(y) y) _
        .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.ToList())


        datasource.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(String))
        datasource.Columns.Add("USERID", GetType(String))
        datasource.Columns.Add("Number_of_orders", GetType(Integer))
        datasource.Columns.Add("8-10h", GetType(Int32))
        datasource.Columns.Add("10-12h", GetType(Int32))
        datasource.Columns.Add("12-14h", GetType(Int32))
        datasource.Columns.Add("14-16h", GetType(Date))
        datasource.Columns.Add("16-18h", GetType(Date))
        datasource.Columns.Add("18-20h", GetType(Date))
        datasource.Columns.Add("20-22h", GetType(Date))

        For Each id As String In dict.Keys
           Dim rows As List(Of DataRow) = dict(id)

            Dim currenttime = From row In rows
                                 Let timeofday = row.Field(Of Date)("time")
                                   Where timeofday.Hour >= 8 AndAlso timeofday.Hour <= 10
                                   Select timeofday
            Dim orderDates As List(Of Date) = currenttime.ToList()

            Dim currenttime1 = From row In rows
                                 Let Timeofday = row.Field(Of Date)("time")
                                   Where Timeofday.Hour >= 10 AndAlso Timeofday.Hour <= 12
                                   Select Timeofday
            Dim orderDates1 As List(Of Date) = currenttime1.ToList()


            Dim currenttime2 = From row In rows
                                Let timeofday = row.Field(Of Date)("time")
                                  Where timeofday.Hour >= 12 AndAlso timeofday.Hour <= 14
                                  Select timeofday
            Dim orderDates2 As List(Of Date) = currenttime1.ToList()


            Dim newRow As DataRow = datasource.Rows.Add
            newRow.ItemArray = {TextBox2.Text, id, orderDates.Count, orderDates1.Count, orderDates2.Count}
        Next id

        DataGridView2.DataSource = datasource    
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
Dim rowsBetween8and10 = From row In dataTable1
                        Let time = row.Field(of TimeSpan)("TIME")
                        Where time.Hours >= 8 AndAlso time.Hours <= 10
```

Now you can use `For Each` to enumerate the rows or `ToList`/`ToArray` to create a collection from the query.

---

**Edit**: according to your comment:

> I have tried your code with For Each rw In rowsBetween8and10 Dim
>   orderdate As New List(Of TimeSpan) orderdate.Add(rw) Next. I'm geting
>   error under add(rw), you can't convert anonymous  type anonyme to timespan?

You could select the `TimeSpan` instead and then use `ToList`:

```
Dim ordersBetween8and10 =
    From row In dataTable1
    Let time = row.Field(Of TimeSpan)("TIME")
    Where time.Hours >= 8 AndAlso time.Hours <= 10
    Select time
Dim orderDates As List(Of TimeSpan) = ordersBetween8and10.ToList()
```

or, to answer your question directly, you have to select the `TimeSpan` from the anonymous type first (on the original query at the top, using LINQ's method-syntax):

```
Dim orderDates As List(Of TimeSpan) = rowsBetween8and10.
    Select(Function(x) x.time).
    Tolist()
```

**Edit** according to your comments, you can use the `TimeOfDay` property and `TimeSpan.FromHours` instead of `Hours`:

```
Dim rowsBetween8and10 =
    From row In dataTable1
    Let time = row.Field(Of Date)("time").TimeOfDay
    Where time >= TimeSpan.FromHours(8) AndAlso time < TimeSpan.FromHours(10)

Dim rowsBetween10and12 =
    From row In dataTable1
    Let time = row.Field(Of Date)("time").TimeOfDay
    Where time >= TimeSpan.FromHours(10) AndAlso time < TimeSpan.FromHours(12)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your help. I have tried your code with For Each rw In rowsBetween8and10 Dim orderdate As New List(Of TimeSpan) orderdate.Add(rw) Next. I'm geting error under add(rw), you can't convert type anonyme to timespan. any idea ? apprecoiated

Comment: @user1858480: So you want a `List(Of TimeSpan)` as result? I have edited my answer to provide to ways.

Comment: Hi Tim, It doesn't seems to find anything. when visualize the data in datatable I could see the time column but for some reason  is in this format 1899-12-30 10:20:00.

Comment: Then it's a `DateTime` and not a `TimeSpan`. Do you want all dates where the time-component is between 8 and 10? Do you get an exception on casting the field to `TimeSpan` (`row.Field(Of TimeSpan)("TIME")`)? If it's a `DateTime` you have to replace `TimeSpan` with `Date` in `Field(Of TimeSpan)` and use it's `TimeOfDay` property which is the `TimeSpan`.

Comment: No I don't get any exception. My original excel sheet that I pull the info from has a time column with only time no date.

Comment: Hi Tim, I got it. I have changed timespan to datetime and I got 4 records. thanks alot for your help:)

Comment: Hi Tim, I spoke too fast:( In datatable I got for ex: 5 records from 10AM to 12. the query between 8&10 gives me 1 record and its the first one 10:20:00. the 2nd query between 10&12 gives me the other 4 records. the 3rd query between 12&14 gives the same 4 records. any idea why ? thanks a lot

Comment: @user1858480: maybe you should better edit your question, add your query and show some sample records, the actual and the desired result since it's difficult to help in the comments.

Comment: @user1858480: So can you also show what you get as result and what you expect? You are grouping by user, so every user-group has three rows. But i think the problem is that your time-groups are overlapping. For example: `Where timeofday.Hour >= 8 AndAlso timeofday.Hour <= 10` and `Where Timeofday.Hour >= 10 AndAlso Timeofday.Hour <= 12` has an overlapping 10. So you would include a row with 10 o'clock into two groups. You need to say `>10` instead of `>=10`.

Comment: I have tried that >10 instead of >=10 and it gives me for example between 8 & 10 I<m suppose to get 3 records but instead it gives me 1

Comment: So you mean you have a row with `08:15` and that should be included since it's hour is between `8` and `10`? You can use `TimeOfDay` instead, i've edited my answer.

Comment: I see why is doing this, TimeOfDay.hour right now it equal to 11. so the query only look for the time span that have 11 hour on it. I have to use something else instead of timeofday

Comment: @user1858480: correct, that's why i've shown you how to use the `TimeOfday` property which returns a `TimeSpan` (the time component of a `DateTime`) instead of the `Hours` property which just returns the full hours `Int32`.

Comment: the output I'm looking for as I stated in edited question is : I need to count the number of records(orders) done by each user in diffrent time span(ex: for 8 to 10)

Comment: Hi Tim, I think I got it by using : Where Time.TimeOfDay > New TimeSpan(10, 0, 0) AndAlso Time.TimeOfDay < New TimeSpan(12, 0, 0) I got the exact number of records

Comment: @user1858480: why haven't you used the code that i've provided in my last edit? You can also use `TimeSpan.FromHours`. You need `>=` and `<`.

Comment: I did but it didn't give the output I was looking for, sorry for any confusement. I apprecied your follow up and your help.